# Java SQL pattern to find some tables in my database

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I'm using database metadata to find some tables in a given schema in database like that:

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connections.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null,"schema_name","table_name_pattern","type");
```

It works, but my problem is that I only want to find tables that begin with `t` and three others tables for which I have the exact names:
`books_table`, `froots`, and `colors`.

How can I make a pattern that gives me only these three tables and the tables that begin with `t`?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is interpreted as as wildcard value for a LIKE condition. So to find all tables starting with `t` use `t%`.

[Quote from the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)

> Some DatabaseMetaData methods take arguments that are String patterns. These arguments all have names such as fooPattern. Within a pattern String, "%" means match any substring of 0 or more characters, and "_" means match any one character.

Note that this is case-sensitive. If you created your tables without quotes (which is what you should be doing) they are stored in lowercase, so `t%` will work fine.

The last parameter should be a string array with all possible "object types". As you want tables, use `{"TABLE"}`. Alternatively if you don't care about the "type", you can also pass `null`

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connections.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null,"schema_name","t%",new String[]{"TABLE"});
```

---

You can't however specify multiple OR conditions. If you want to find if other tables exist where you can't use a wildcard, you will have to call `getTables()` once for each table name.

Another option is to simply get all tables from that schema, then discard those that you don't want while processing the ResultSet. That is most probably faster than using multiple calls to `getTables()`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem time ago, and the answer is no, you can't do it this way.

The JDBC metadata classes have only very limited functionality.

However, you can query the engine metadata directly. For example you can do:

```
select * 
from pg_catalog.pg_tables
where schemaname = 'public'
  and tablename like 't%' or tablename in ('books_table', 'froots', 'colors')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i found it very usefull, but in the project where i am working they don't like to see SQL querys in java code....what i've done Works ..i juste want to right a pattern which let me find tables that begins with t and the three others tables and use it in the getTables() method